# How to calculate with respect to money??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if A and B undertake to do a piece of work for Rs.108 .
 A can do it  in 5 days while B  can do in 7 days . 
if both of them finished the work together , how much shell B get s?

I am confusing with money here !!

How to calculate with respect to money??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should think of terms of rates here, not times. And we could base the payment on the rates.

$A$ can do $1$ job in $5$ days, so $A$'s rate of work is $1/5$.

$B$ can do $1$ job in $7$ days, so $B$'s rate of work is $1/7$.

Their combined rate is $\frac15+\frac17=\frac{12}{35}$.

$B$'s fraction of that work is $(\frac17)/(\frac{12}{35})=\frac5{12}$.

Therefore, $B$ should get $\frac5{12} \cdot 108=45$ Rs.

This is the same answer as Jasper's but with more detail (and more confidence, I hope).

Answer (score 2):

$A$ can do $\frac{7}{12}$ of the work and $B$ can do $\frac{5}{12}$ of the work in this period, so $B$ should get $\frac{5}{12}\times 108$ Rs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to understand why the A:B split should be $7$ to $5$:  Suppose you had $12$ jobs to do.  Then A, by himself, could do $7$ of them in $35$ days, while B could do the other $5$ in the same amount of time.